# The arithmetic mean of $X$ when arithmetic mean of $X^2 = 29$.

Tags: arithmetic

Sorry if my question is a beginner because of my mathematical knowledge is low.

arithmetic mean is :

$$
\overline x=\dfrac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}n
$$

What method can solve it?

$$
\overline{X^2}=29\quad\Rightarrow\,\text{Not }\left(\overline X\right)^2 \\\,\\
\overline X=\boxed{?}\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\,\,\,
$$

I got the square root but answer is not right.
For example :

$$
\overline X=\dfrac{1+2}2=\dfrac32=1.5 \\\,\\
\overline{X^2}=\dfrac{1+4}2=\dfrac52=2.5 \\\,\\
\sqrt{2.5}\approx1.581\ne1.5
$$

Comment: You can't solve it, you need more information. All that you know is that $\lvert \overline{x}\rvert \leqslant \sqrt{\overline{x^2}}$.

Comment: If you knew the variance of these numbers then you would almost be able to get the mean (upto a sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of why it's impossible with the given information. Suppose $x_1 = \sqrt{29}$, $x_2 = \sqrt{29}$. Then $\overline{x^2} = 29$, and $\overline{x} = \sqrt{29}$.

Now suppose $x_1 = \sqrt{29}$, $x_2 = -\sqrt{29}$. Again $\overline{x^2} = 29$, but now $\overline{x} = 0$. So we have two sets with the same $\overline{x^2}$ but different $\overline{x}$. Therefore, without more data, it's impossible to get $\overline{x}$ from $\overline{x^2}$.